# Is there a way to change FieldCodes values in multiple RTF documents using powershell

Tags: powershell, rtf

Currently our RTF contains { INCLUDETEXT  "fileSign02.rtf"  * MERGEFORMAT } want to replace it with { INCLUDETEXT  "fileSign02.rtf"  } is there anyway can be handled in batch for all RTF files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to add a filter to get-childitem depending on your requiements.

```
get-childitem c:\your_rtf_folder | %{(get-content $_.Fullname) -replace "\* MERGEFORMAT","" | set-content $_.Fullname}
```